# Sun Java HttpServer - Either slow in serving requests or wasting resources (TIME_WAIT/CLOSE_WAIT)

Tags: java, apache, apache-commons-httpclient, sun, com.sun.net.httpserver

First,

I've searched a lot to find a solution but were not able to find an appropriate one.

**Environment**

- (productive) Mongoose WebServer replies to simple GET-requests (all data are transmitted via QueryString)
- Apache HttpClient (single instance!) used to make hundreds of thousands single requests sequentially.
- Apache HttpClient interacting with mongoose works quite well

  ```
  // after each request
  getMethod.releaseConnection();
  ...
  ```

**Problem**

- (Mock) implementation of WebServer with Sun HttpServer works fine with FireFox / Curl
- Using Apache HttpClient as with running against productive Server, performance is horrible (~ 1 request/second) on client
- Using Apache HttpClient with following code found on the net results in

  - vast performance gain on client
  - resource waste due to as many open sockets in CLOSE_WAIT state as requests processed (until no more FDs ara available!)

Code:

```
HttpConnectionManager mgr = httpClient.getHttpConnectionManager();
    if (mgr instanceof SimpleHttpConnectionManager) {
    ((SimpleHttpConnectionManager)mgr).shutdown();
}
```

**Obviously I am mising something in the http server implementation, which causes this extreme "sloweness"**

Any hint/help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

---

### **Code**

**HttpServer**

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        //System.setProperty("sun.net.httpserver.maxIdleConnections", "10");
        //System.setProperty("sun.net.httpserver.idleInterval", "2000");

        HttpServer server = HttpServer.create();

        server.bind(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 11111), -1);
        InetSocketAddress addr = server.getAddress();
        HttpContext contextSearch = server.createContext("/search.to",
                new TrufflesSearchHandler());

        contextSearch.getFilters().add(new ParameterFilter());
        server.setExecutor(null); // creates a default executor
        server.start();
    }
```

**HttpHandler**

```java
    static class SearchHandler implements HttpHandler {
        private JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

        public void handle(HttpExchange exchange) throws IOException {
            Map<String, Object> params = (Map<String, Object>) exchange
                    .getAttribute("parameters");
            String expectedResponse = "";
            int expectedHitPlace = -1;

            try {
                expectedResponse = (String) params.get("expectedResponse");
                expectedHitPlace = Integer.parseInt((String) params
                        .get("expectedHitPlace"));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            JSONArray resultArray = null;
            try {
                resultArray = (JSONArray) jsonParser.parse(new String(Base64
                        .decodeBase64(expectedResponse)));
                fillResponseWithDummyData(resultArray, expectedHitPlace);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String response = "{ \"results\": " + resultArray + "}";

            Headers headers = exchange.getResponseHeaders();
            headers.add("Connection", "keep-alive");
            headers.add("Content-Type", "text/plain");
            headers.add("Content-length", "" + response.getBytes().length);
            // headers.add("Keep-Alive", "timeout=5 max=10");
            exchange.sendResponseHeaders(200, 0);
            // exchange.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.getBytes().length);
            OutputStream os = exchange.getResponseBody();
            os.write(response.getBytes());
            os.flush();
            os.close();
            // exchange.close();
        }
```

**ParameterFilter**

```java
@SuppressWarnings("restriction")
public class ParameterFilter extends Filter {

    @Override
    public String description() {
        return "Parses the requested URI for parameters";
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(HttpExchange exchange, Chain chain)
        throws IOException {
        parseGetParameters(exchange);
        parsePostParameters(exchange);
        chain.doFilter(exchange);
    }    

    private void parseGetParameters(HttpExchange exchange)
        throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

        Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        URI requestedUri = exchange.getRequestURI();
        String query = requestedUri.getRawQuery();
        parseQuery(query, parameters);
        exchange.setAttribute("parameters", parameters);
    }

    private void parsePostParameters(HttpExchange exchange)
        throws IOException {

        if ("post".equalsIgnoreCase(exchange.getRequestMethod())) {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            Map<String, Object> parameters =
                (Map<String, Object>)exchange.getAttribute("parameters");
            InputStreamReader isr =
                new InputStreamReader(exchange.getRequestBody(),"utf-8");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String query = br.readLine();
            parseQuery(query, parameters);
        }
    }

     private void parseQuery(String query, Map<String, Object> parameters)
         throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
         String encoding = System.getProperty("file.encoding");
         if (query != null) {
             String pairs[] = query.split("[&]");

             for (String pair : pairs) {
                 String param[] = pair.split("[=]");

                 String key = null;
                 String value = null;
                 if (param.length > 0) {
                     key = URLDecoder.decode(param[0],
                         encoding);
                 }

                 if (param.length > 1) {
                     value = URLDecoder.decode(param[1],
                         encoding);
                 }

                 if (parameters.containsKey(key)) {
                     Object obj = parameters.get(key);
                     if(obj instanceof List<?>) {
                         List<String> values = (List<String>)obj;
                         values.add(value);
                     } else if(obj instanceof String) {
                         List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
                         values.add((String)obj);
                         values.add(value);
                         parameters.put(key, values);
                     }
                 } else {
                     parameters.put(key, value);
                 }
             }
         }
    }

}
```

Comment: If you can't answer it I would look into using Jetty which is an actual 'real' server you can embed into your application.

Comment: It's just a 'stupid' mock, so generally there is no need for more functionality, and implementation is already done. So I would prefer to solve this issue, and I suspect the solution to be a tiny modification / correction.